# Telnet - Android console command does not have sms command

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use telnet to send an SMS to Android Emulator, but my Android console command help does not have SMS or call command. See below:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot can't be seen. It would be better to put the error or any other necessary info in text.

Comment: Thank David for edit my screenshot.
I want to use sms command but like you can see it's unknown command.